# How to set a variable based on a DOM element's background color in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div *ngFor="let art of artfacts" class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <img [src]=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Now, I'd like to set different sources to my image based on "parent's" background color. How could I achieve that during DOM rendering?**

Comment: got color into 'art'?

Comment: you have two options: 1) have a property in art that denotes background color 2) create a directive for image and access the parent's background color and set src accordingly

Comment: I did not have color in my object so it was difficult. Now I have handled it with another property in my object (which is similar to other suggestions given here by everyone) so it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you get color into art object then you can set like

```
<div *ngFor="let art of artfacts" class="parent" style="background-color:{{art.color}}">
  <div class="child">
    <img [src]=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a color and an image src for each `art` object then do:

```
<div *ngFor="let art of artfacts" class="parent" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': art.color">
  <div class="child">
    <img [src]="art.image?.src">
  </div>
</div>
```